Apache additional directive to hide folder contents not work
I have a project with ngix as reverse proxy-server and Apache, i'm trying to restrict access to the files contained in a specific folder only to the server ifself.
So this is an example:
domain: mysite.test
server ip: 100.100.1.1
hide folder path: /var/www/vhosts/mysite.test/httpdocs/foldertohide
hidden file https://mysite.test/foldertohide/img1234.png
This what i put inside additional https and https directive of Apache:
<Directory "/var/www/vhosts/mysite.test/httpdocs/foldertohide">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 100.100.1.1
</Directory>

At this point I shouldn't be able to reach the URL for the hidden file, but if I enter it into the browser instead of a 403 error i see the image.
I have used the same directives in others old projects, why they not work anymore ?

Fairly typical is that Apache will only see the IP-address of the reverse proxy and not the actual IP-address of the site visitor. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html - In addition https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html   "The Allow, Deny, and Order directives, provided by mod_access_compat, are deprecated and will go away in a future version. You should avoid using them, and avoid outdated tutorials recommending their use."

With apache 2.4 this is the correct version :
<Directory /var/www/vhosts/mysite.test/httpdocs/foldertohide >
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 100.100.1.1
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>

